# Inequality between sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be sequences of positive numbers. Is it true that: If for every $\epsilon>0$ the inequality $x_n^{1+\epsilon}>y_n$ holds for all $n$, then $x_n\geq y_n$ for all $n$?

Comment: Note that your question is actually unrelated to sequences. If $x^{1+\epsilon}>y$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ then $x \ge y$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Fix any $n$. If $x_n^{1+\varepsilon}\ge y_n$ for all $\varepsilon> 0$, then $y_n\le \inf\limits_{\varepsilon >0} x_n^{1+\varepsilon}$. If $x_n\ge 1$, then $x_n=\inf\limits_{\varepsilon>0} x_n^{1+\varepsilon}$. If $0<x_n<1$, then $\inf\limits_{\varepsilon>0}x_n^{1+\varepsilon}=0<x_n$. Either way, $y_n\le x_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , for each $n_0\in \Bbb N$ take $\epsilon_n = \dfrac{1}{n}$ then $x_{n_0} \ ^ {1 + 1/n} \gt y_{n_0}$ for each $n$ which means $x_{n_0} \ge y_{n_0}$